# VueJS - Transition group is animating initial render of a list of components even though "appear" prop is false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm facing an odd behaviour with **transition-group**.

I have this css transition:

```
.slide-fade-pop-enter-active {
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.slide-fade-pop-enter {
  background-color: $color-yellow-light;
  transform: translateY(3px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And I have a **Cart** component and **CartItem** subcomponents.
Inside the **Cart** I have **CartItem**s like so:

```
<transition-group name="slide-fade-pop" tag="ul" class="cart__content">
    <cart-item v-for="(item, index) in items"
               :key="index">
    </cart-item>
</transition-group>
```

This is triggering initial rendering animation, even though, as you see, I'm not using the "appear" attribute/prop which, as documented, triggers initial rendering animation.

When I switch the **CartItem** component for a simple **li** (which, in fact is the **CartItem**), like so:

```
<transition-group name="slide-fade-pop" tag="ul" class="cart__content">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items"
               :key="index">
    </li>
</transition-group>
```

The transition behaves as intended. No initial render, subsequent additions to list are animated.

Is this a bug or a feature and I'm missing something on my subcomponent?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Craig no. Just ended having a loading screen hiding the mess

Comment: Workaround is to add a `v-if="items.length"` to the transition-group, but still feels like I'm missing something.